# Как словить onmouseover внешнего элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как словить onmouseover внешнего элемента? Проблема в том, что когда курсор попадает на вложенный див, то тогда события не работает нормально. Как сделать, что-бы пользователь  даже, когда попадает на вложенный элемент, событие на внешнем диве все равно срабатывало?

```
    <div onmouseover="murka()">
          <div><p></p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наведите курсор на [черный квадрат](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/9df6H/). Потом наведите на серый квадрат. Есть разница? Нет, потому что событие onmouseover возникает в любом случае.

Comment: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/mouse#poryadok-i-chastota

Comment: Вероятно, нужно более качественно формировать свой вопрос. Итак, что вам надо-то?

Comment: мне надо обойти вот эту фишку "Можно зайти во внутренний элемент, не проходя через внешний."

Comment: Там же написано: "Точно также можно выйти из внутреннего элемента, не проходя через внешний. Всего-то надо быстро двигать мышкой" :)

Comment: Да нет. Смотрите, у меня есть два элемента один вложенный в другой, мне надо, что-бы всегда срабатывало событие onmouseover, даже если ты быстро навел на внутренний элемент
Мне надо просто onmouseover на внутренних написать?

Comment: Попробуйте, почему нет?

Comment: Почитайте про всплытие и перехват и будет вам счастье.